# Will increasing the initial concentration of a reactant result in more time for the reaction to go to completion?

Tags: concentration

I understand that increasing the concentration of a reactant increases its instantaneous reaction rate, but shouldn’t the amount of time for the overall reaction to go to completion increase?

For example, in the 2015 AP Chemistry frq 5, the answer to part (b) is that increasing the concentration of the food colouring increases the time for the reaction mixture to reach an absorbance near zero.

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/studying-for-ap-chemistry-exam/2015-ap-chemistry-free-response-questions/v/2015-ap-chemistry-free-response-5

Comment: Yes, it will, so what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Reactions never go to 100% completion. A reaction is considered as achieved when the  amounts of reactants and products tend to respect the equilibrium constant of the reaction.

Comment: It is somewhat complicated by the fact that you need to be very careful when making general statements in chemistry. There are frequently exceptions. For instance is (1) Zero-order reaction? (2) The other reactant  the limiting reagent? (3) Is the exothermic such that the increase in temperature greatly accelerates the rate of reaction? (3)